# Exchange Online sending mail on behalf of another domain

Tags: exchange

I want to use Exchange Online to mail on behalf of another domain. So....

An email from `consumer@gmail.com` is sent to `complaints@customer.com`

The mailbox for `complaints@customer.com` forwards the mail to `complaints@thedomainIcontrol.com` (this mailbox is configure in Exchange Online and I own it)

An application I'm developing uses graph API to pull emails from the mailbox `complaints@thedomainIcontrol.com`

The application creates a response and sets the "from" address to `complaints@customer.com`. The customer has set up DKIM/SPF etc

Will Exchange Online complain about the from address being  `complaints@customer.com`?

Answer (score 0):

No, it will not work to send email as `complaints@customer.com`, Exchange Online will probably not even send it, as you're literately spoofing email for the domain `customer.com`. And even if you would manage to send it, it would fail DKIM (as the keys used to sign it are wrong), and probably also SPF (as long as your customer isn't using Exchange Online at least).

An easy workaround is to request an e-mail account from your customer, and send the e-mail using their infrastructure.

Another workaround I'm particularly fond of is to assign a subdomain for applications like this, say `app1.customer.com`, and then you could use that to send e-mail as `complaints@app1.customer.com`, since the SPF and DKIM settings can be set differently for a subdomain, you can even add it to your own infrastructure if you like.

Comment: Im suprised by this. From what I understand of DKIM so long as we provide the customer with the private key and they apply it to their DNS this would work?

Comment: That would work, just make sure to use a different qualifier than they are using. The same goes for SPF if the records aren't the same as yours.

Comment: I think this will not work.

Comment: @JayceYang care to elaborate?

Comment: When I tried the graph API responsed with a 403 ErrorSendAsDenied

Comment: Because this is spoofing, Office 365 let you send as verfified domain